# How can I append the option without duplicate whenever click?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a dropdown button for filtering the data. The value of the dropdown list will contain the categories of a column from the dataset.

I already have a function to get the categories from the dataset, now I just want to add it to the dropdown list.

This is my code for add new option to the dropdown button:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
        function addOption() { 
            optionText = 'Premium'; 
            optionValue = 'premium'; 
  
            $('#select1').append(`<option value="${optionValue}"> 
                                       ${optionText} 
                                  </option>`); 
        } 
</script>
```

This is the code for dropdown list:

```
<form class="simple_form form-inline" method="get">
        <div class="form-group select required">
            <label for="basic-url" class="form-label">Product</label>
            <select class="select required form-control" id="select1" onclick="addOption()">
                <option value="">- Discipline -</option>
                <option value="1">HW</option>
                <option value="2">SW</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </form>
```

How to make the dropdown add the option once, because with my code, whenever I click the button, it will add the option again.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css"
        integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v6.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.4/Chart.min.js" 
        integrity="sha512-d9xgZrVZpmmQlfonhQUvTR7lMPtO7NkZMkA0ABN3PHCbKA5nqylQ/yWlFAyY6hYgdF1Qh6nYiuADWwKB4C2WSw==" 
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <form class="simple_form form-inline" method="get">
        <div class="form-group select required">
            <label for="basic-url" class="form-label">Product</label>
            <select class="select required form-control" id="select1" onclick="addOption()">
                <option value="">- Discipline -</option>
                <option value="1">HW</option>
                <option value="2">SW</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </form>

    <script type="text/javascript"> 
        function addOption() { 
            optionText = 'Premium'; 
            optionValue = 'premium'; 
  
            $('#select1').append(`<option value="${optionValue}"> 
                                       ${optionText} 
                                  </option>`); 
        } 
    </script> 
    
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
```

Or you can try it with [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0b5sv941/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [jQuery's `.one`-binding](https://api.jquery.com/one/) to only execute code once. Also, you should not use inline event listeners.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#select1').one('click', function() {
    optionText = 'Premium';
    optionValue = 'premium';
    $(this).append(`<option value="${optionValue}">${optionText}</option>`);
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form class="simple_form form-inline" method="get">
  <div class="form-group select required">
    <label for="basic-url" class="form-label">Product</label>
    <select class="select required form-control" id="select1">
      <option value="">- Discipline -</option>
      <option value="1">HW</option>
      <option value="2">SW</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

I am wondering if this is what you are looking for: https://jsfiddle.net/m5jetdqc/

```
    <form class="simple_form form-inline" method="get">
        <div class="form-group select required">
            <label for="basic-url" class="form-label">Product</label>
            <select class="select required form-control" id="select1" onclick="!added && addOption()">
                <option value="">- Discipline -</option>
                <option value="1">HW</option>
                <option value="2">SW</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </form>

    <script type="text/javascript"> 
        let added = false;
        function addOption() { 
            optionText = 'Premium'; 
            optionValue = 'premium'; 
  
            $('#select1').append(`<option value="${optionValue}"> 
                                       ${optionText} 
                                  </option>`); 
            added = true
        } 
    </script>
```

Comment: Introducing global variables for the job, are you serious?

Comment: Your answer is clearly better. My answer sucks and just barely solves the question, but I hope the idea gets home.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove last element of list before inserting new one. Use below code to remove last element from dropdown:

```
$("select[id=select1] option:last").remove();
```